# Javascript function works but returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, return

I'm trying to build a function that looks for all elements with the 'filter' rel in my page, and then adds them to a js object.

The function itself seems to work fine when I use console.log within the function, however, when I attempt to call the function anywhere it returns undefined.  I realize that this is a common issue with asynchronous calls, but I didn't think that was the case here:

```
function getFilters() {
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var filters = new Array();
    $("[rel=filter]").each(function(i,e){
        var type = $(e).attr('type');
        if(type == 'checkbox') { if($(e).is(':checked')) var val = $(e).prop('checked'); }
        else if(type == 'radio') { if($(e).is(':checked')) var val = $(e).val(); }
        else var val = $(e).val();
        if(val) filters.push({name : $(e).attr('name'), value : val});
    });
    return filters;
});
}
```

Again, when I run console.log(filters); in place of return filters; my data pulls up just fine.  When I attempt to return it though, it just results in undefined.  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You aren't returning anything from the function; you're returning from a jQuery callback.

Comment: You should not include the DOM ready callback within your function but rather call your function from within the DOM ready callback.

Comment: I don't think you are fully aware of what the `ready` callback is needed for. See https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/.

Comment: I had tried removing the .ready callback, but then I was getting "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" in my console

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're expecting `getFilters()` to return a value, that's your problem. All getFilters() does is register an event handler (it doesn't return anything).

You probably want something like this:

```
function getFilters() {
    var filters = new Array();
    $("[rel=filter]").each(function(i,e){
        var type = $(e).attr('type');
        if(type == 'checkbox') { if($(e).is(':checked')) var val = $(e).prop('checked'); }
        else if(type == 'radio') { if($(e).is(':checked')) var val = $(e).val(); }
        else var val = $(e).val();
        if(val) filters.push({name : $(e).attr('name'), value : val});
    });
    return filters;
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    var filters = getFilters();
    // do something with filters
});
```

Comment: It sounds like outside of the DOM ready callback, my issue is due to how I've set up my files.  Annoyingly my functions are in a different file than my DOM ready callback.  That makes wrapping it in (function($){})(jQuery); difficult, and so it seems like without the DOM ready callback within the function itself jquery is basically getting ignored.  Is there any way to get around this when the functions are in a seperate file?

Comment: If you don't mind polluting your namespace, just define getFilter() at the global scope and you can call it from anywhere. I'll update my answer to show that (it's just removing the first and last line).

Comment: Thanks, James!  I did that and changes my $ in the function to jQuery and it seems to be working now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the function getFilters actually returns nothing, because it just invokes jQuery(document).ready(...);, just binding a function to run later. The anonymous function that returns filters is actually invoked after page is ready, but caller of getFilters does not take the return value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define filters var one level up or make it global. Now it's local in the function defined by jQuery, so it's not visible in getFilters.